# Wagtail sitemap produces VariableDoesNotExist error in console

Tags: django, sitemap, wagtail

We've noticed this error (below ) cropping up when running the Wagtail sitemap.xml, we haven't modified it, and it does work. These errors are just in the console/logs locally. Our server person wants to know if we should worry about these or not?

```
Exception while resolving variable 'priority' in template 'wagtailsitemaps/sitemap.xml'.

VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [priority] in u"{u'lastmod': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 10, 57, 43, 759421, tzinfo=<UTC>), u'location': u'http://localhost/streamfield-page/news-index/news-1/'}"
```

Comment: if it "does work", then you should possibly not worry about it - but does it _really_ work ? Oh and yes: maybe you should report this on the project's tracker ?

Comment: Does your News listing page have a 'Priority' set, or not?

Comment: No, our news model is just based on the wagtail demosite one